# How do I test the class of an element selected with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that is supposed to make even rows blue (layout-2 has a blue background). I don't want this to work for the table row with class 'add-task'.  For some reason, the code is still turning add-task blue even though it shouldn't.  How do i fix this?

```
var it = $('.add-task');
if (it.className == 'add-task'){
}
else{
    $('table tbody tr:even').addClass('layout-2');
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume there is some missing code here? If you select by class `add-task`, your first condition will __always__ be true (using the correct comparison.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys.  I'm looking through all these answers now.

Comment: @Mathletics, there's no missing code.  The if statement is blank because I want nothing to happen if the class is add-task.

Comment: But you are selecting the item by class `add-task`. How would the item you just selected then __not__ have _the class by which it was selected_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

className does not work because jQuery wraps DOM elements in a helper class to make them easier to use.  However, you can build your condition directly into your selector:

```
$('table tbody tr:even not:(.add-task)').addClass('layout-2');
```

Answer (score 1):

`it` is a jQuery object, not a DOM node. And jQuery has a useful [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method that you can use:

```
var it = $('.add-task');
if (it.hasClass('add-task')) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
};
```

Comment: @jcsanyi because an element can have multiple classes, for instance, so if you want to check against the `class` attribute, you need to do substring matches (and handle whitespace, etc).

Comment: @jcsanyi the explanation is that `it` is not a DOM element but a jQuery object...

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `.attr('class')` to get the class of the selected element. or you can use `.hasClass('className')` to check whether the selected element has that class or not.

Try,

```
var it = $('.add-task');

//But .hasClass() should be a recommended one here
if(it.attr('class').indexOf('add-task') > -1){
  $('table tbody tr:even').addClass('layout-2');
}
```

Or you can use `.toggleClass('className',switch)`

```
$('table tbody tr:even').toggleClass('layout-2',it.hasClass('add-task'));
```

Or you can use the native JS object,

```
var it = $('.add-task');
if(it[0].className).indexOf('add-task') > -1){
  $('table tbody tr:even').addClass('layout-2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remember that jquery returns an array of dom elements. `it[0].className == 'add-task'` will do the trick assuming its the only elem with that class. if the element is unique consider using an id instead.